# What's the difference between the snap folder in /home/UserName and the snap folder in root (/)?

Tags: directory, root, home-directory, snap

What's the difference between the `snap` folder in `/home/<UserName>` and the `snap` folder in root (`/`)?  I'm trying to get a grasp on where programs and their files are stored when you install them.  The first and only program I have installed on my machine is Spotify.

I noticed that there were two `spotify` folders within two separate `snap` folders.  One in the home directory and one in the root directory.

#### Questions

- Why are there two `snap` folders?
- Why are there two `spotify` folders?
- Are they different in any way (the `snap` and `spotify` folders)?

**NOTE:** I installed Spotify via the Ubuntu Software application, not via the Terminal.

Answer (score 7):

The `/snap`-directory contains a file named `README`:

```
This directory presents installed snap packages.

It has the following structure:

/snap/bin                   - Symlinks to snap applications.
/snap/<snapname>/<revision> - Mountpoint for snap content.
/snap/<snapname>/current    - Symlink to current revision, if enabled.

DISK SPACE USAGE

The disk space consumed by the content under this directory is
minimal as the real snap content never leaves the .snap file.
Snaps are *mounted* rather than unpacked.

For further details please visit
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-snap-directory/2817
```

To sum it up, this directory contains the mount-points for your snaps and several symlinks which are needed by `snapd`.

The directory `/home/<username>/snap` holds the configuration files for your snaps.

Comment: That clears some things up.  Follow up, so when I run sudo apt-get remove <application name> or sudo apt-get purge <application name>, will that remove the <application name> files in both snap directories?

Comment: snaps are not managed with the `apt`-command, to remove a snap, use `sudo snap remove snapname` instead. The files in your home directory will not get removed automatically, this has to be done manually.