# snap folder in root is very heavy while snap folder in home is light

Tags: 20.04, mount, root, snap, home-directory

I think my snap folders in root and home are swapped. Indeed, according to the answer of this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131944/whats-the-difference-between-the-snap-folder-in-home-username-and-the-snap-fol), all the configuration files of my snaps should be in the snap folder stored in `/home` while there should only be mount points in the one stored in `/root`. However, it seems to be the other way round (18GB of memory used in root and 1.3GB in `/home`):

[image: /snap hard drive usage]

[image: /home/{username}/snap hard drive usage]

Q1: How can I swap these two folders? (I guess simply moving them won't work)

Q2: I also have a folder `snapd` in `/var/lib` which is 7gb. Is this normal?

Q3: I noticed that two versions of each snap are stored: can I safely remove the older ones to save space?

infos: Ubuntu 20.04, Dell XPS 15

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1303252/edit) your question and use copy and paste of your text instead of screenshots.  Also, what is the output of `lsblk | grep snap`?  I think you will see that all the mounted snaps reside in the `/snap` folder and not the `~/snap` folder.  From looking at your pics, your folders seem to be correct.  The size of the `snapd` depends on how many snaps you have installed.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036633/how-to-remove-disabled-unused-snap-packages-with-a-single-line-of-command if you want to remove the extra unused snaps.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1156686/590937) might be of interest for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Indeed, according to the answer of this post, all the configuration
> files of my snaps should be in the snap folder stored in home while
> there should only be mount points in the one stored in root. However,
> it seems to be the other way round [...].

This point is correct, but you're neglecting the fact that `du` doesn't care that something is mounted there. You asked it to tell you how big the files are in a specific location, and it told you. Check the output of the `mount` command and you'll notice that nearly everything in the `/snap` directory is just a mount point. Everything else in there is just a symlink. What you're seeing is correct, don't worry! You don't want to swap anything.

> Q2: I also have a folder snapd in /var/lib which is 7gb. Is this normal?

Yes, this is where the individual snaps are stored (from where they're mounted into `/snap/` somewhere). This is normal.

> Q3: I noticed that two versions of each snap are stored: can I safely remove the older ones to save space?

You may; the reason snapd keeps old snaps around is in case you need to revert to an older one. You can see them all with `snap list <snap name> --all`. If you're confident you don't need old revisions, you can remove them using `sudo snap remove <snap name> --revision=<snap revision>`. Note that you can change the snapd configuration to retain a different number of snaps:

```
$ snap set system refresh.retain=<number>
```